# Typescript TypeError with es2022 but not with es2021

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc, es2022

I'm trying to update the target property of the tsconfig.json file from es2015 to es2022.
But I get an error when running the tests, which I think only use tsc without babel:

> Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.177 (Mac OS 10.15.7)  TypeError: Cannot
> read properties of undefined (reading 'getSomeValue')

The code causing this problem:

```
export class MyService {
    private xyz$ = this.otherService.getSomeValue().pipe(...

    constructor(private readonly otherService: SettingsService) {}
}
```

My guess the error is related to the new class fields features introduced in es2022? But I don't see why it should be a problem here? It's running fine with es2021.

I'm not sure if the tsconfig.json helps?

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2022",
        "module": "es2022",
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a runtime error, suggesting that `otherService` is `undefined`.  Without seeing how this code is being accessed, trying to understand why this is happening would just be a wild guess.  a [mcve] would be necessary here.

Comment: Your `xyz$` default value is based on `otherService` and you are relying on `otherService` being initialised first. This behaviour (as far as I can see) is not guaranteed so when you switched from ES2015 to ES2022 you probably ended up with a different transpiled code that changed the order in which these were initialised. You should be more explicit on how you initialise `xyz$` e.g. do it in the constructor

Comment: It works when I initialize them in the constructor. But I'm not sure why this is needed now.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 related issues:

- [Class field initialization order different between target ES2021 and ES2022 #52331](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52331)
- [useDefineWithClassFields should use-before-init error when class property initializer refers to parameter property #50971](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50971)

As far as I understand the reasoning, accessing a constructor parameter property in a class property is expected to fail with `use-before-init`, but the typescript compiler currently does not emit this error.

```js
class Test {
  // constructor that sets a field
  constructor(private param: Param){
  }

  // this is expected to fail - this.param is NOT assigned yet
  a = this.param.a;
}
```